# Do I need the Suhosin security patch on a VPS?

Tags: php, suhosin

I have a VPS with Linode and the out-of-the-box Ubuntu server setup comes with the [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html) PHP security patch. The annoying problem is that it's effecting a few things, namely CakePHP session/cookies and a couple of side affects with phpMyAdmin.

As I'm the only person with any sort of login to the server and will be writing all code on it, is the suhosin patch completely necessary? I'm also using frameworks and what is generally accepted as "secure" software. Is it easy to remove if I don't need it?

**Update**
For those who want to remove it, this command worked for me: `apt-get remove php5-suhosin`, additionally, you may want to remove any config files (named `suhosin.ini`) that might have been left behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you should not use Suhosin not only because of the problems which you face, but also because it dead project for me. Last news are from 2007 and insite forum long time dead too. I personally disable it on my dedicated server because of the too many conflicts with 3rd party apps. Also I notice a some big load from time to time with enabled suhosin.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY need to disable it, you can do it, but it's a major pain in the ass since you have to reinstall PHP. Suhosin comes in two parts: a module and a patch to the PHP source. You can just unistall the module, for the patch, you need a fresh install of PHP.